# How can i create reusable blocks in EasyAdmin Symfony

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have an entity page and i would like to add blocks of different types and display them in the form when i select one (Image, text and image or just text). All dynamically without being pre-defined in the administration (like a cms).

HomePage

- title
- description
- blocks [text, text-image, image]

  - if text create new field text
  - if text-image create new field text and new field image
  - if text again create new field text

I dont know how to make a form to be like reapeater one with adding new block or removing existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will put an answer instead.
I am not sure I get your question. If you're trying to configure the fields, you need to configure them in your CrudController:

- TextField
- ImageField
- etc. as per the documentation

If you're trying to have a more CMS like approach, where you can move things around, you may want to check SonataAdmin instead. It is much more complicated but provide CMS capabilities EasyAdmin does not.

Comment: Yes it's more like CMS. I'm gonna try with SonataAdmin.
Thanks.